# Selenium click a button if the parameter is true

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to create a function which takes a parameter and if the parament is True then the button is click otherwise no. Can i use this?

```
def buttonClick(self, Button):
    if Button == True:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('button').click
```

Comment: Yes, you can use this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main things to fix from the top of my head:

- you can avoid having `== True` part
- you are not calling the `click` method - add the `()`

Fixed version:

```
def buttonClick(self, should_click_button):
    if should_click_button:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()
```

Sample usage:

```
instance = MyClass()
instance.buttonClick(True)
instance.buttonClick(False)
```

You can also set the default value for the argument:

```
def buttonClick(self, should_click_button=False):
    if should_click_button:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()
```

Now, if you don't need to click the button, simply don't pass the argument:

```
instance = MyClass()
instance.buttonClick(True)
instance.buttonClick()
```

Comment: sorry i am still new to programming. what parameter i need to put in to the should_click_button in order to use it?

Comment: @ChiragVerma updated the answer with some samples, hope that helps.